# Question mark in Prometheus metrics_path gets encoded

Tags: prometheus

Because Prometheus only supports text metrics and many tool return metrics in json (like Finatra, Spring Boot), I created a simple proxy which translates the json into text. Because I want to use it for multiple sources, the target from which the actual metrics are to be retrieved is set via a query param.

The metrics url looks like this:

`/metrics?prefix=finatra&url=http://<ip>:9990/admin/metrics.json`

This works fine in a browser or curl.
However, in Prometheus the '?' gets encoded to '%3F' and therefore the request fails:

`/metrics%3Fprefix=finatra&url=http://<ip>:9990/admin/metrics.json`

How can I prevent Prometheus from encoding the <kbd>?</kbd>?
Is this a bug in Prometheus?
I already tried escaping with `%` or `\`, using unicode etc, but still no luck.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This behaviour is correct, as the metrics path is a path - not an arbitrary suffix on the protocol, host and port.

You're looking for the [params](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#%3Cscrape_config%3E) configuration option:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'somename'
    params:
      prefix: ['finatra']
      url: ['http://:9090/admin/metrics.json']
```

Comment: Any advice on doing:
params:
   match[]: {__name__="up"}

?  going through a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT Not applicable for this use-case**:
Just in addition of brian-brazil his answer, you still need to specify the metrics path

```
  - job_name: 'somename'
    metrics_path: metrics  
    params:
      prefix: ['finatra']
      url: ['http://:9090/admin/metrics.json']
```

Because metrics is the base where you want to specify parameters.

Comment: Metrics path must be specified only if id differs from default `/metrics`: [`[ metrics_path: <path> | default = /metrics ]`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config). Additionally, it generally should start with `/`.

Comment: Ahh, well I had to add: '/plugin/prometheus/metrics/', so thought was good to add, but didn't know about the default. Thanks!