# Prometheus params encoding

Tags: prometheus

I was able to use params configuration in `scrape_config` to eliminate the url encoding based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172415/question-mark-in-prometheus-metrics-path-gets-encoded) post, however, the resulted url is out of order. The url I need is

```
/metrics/exporter?endpoint=<IP>&apitoken=<API Token>
```

However, prometheus displays it as

```
/metrics/exporter?apitoken=<API_Token>&endpoint=<IP>
```

As you can see, the field `apitoken` and `endpoint` are reversed. As a result, it's not grabbing the data.

Below is the `scrape_config` snippet:

```
- job_name: "job1"
  params:
  endpoint: ['<IP>']
  apitoken: ['<API Token>']
 metrics_path: "/metrics/exporter"
```

I believe I'm close to getting it but I'm just not sure where I need to look at. I have already swapped the field `endpoint` and `apitoken` in the `scrape_config` but that doesn't seem to work.